# Django rest framework: Do I really need two separate serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an `APIView` class with `post` and `patch`. The serializer for this class is a `ModelSerializer`.

The thing is: I would like `post` to require **all** fields, but `patch` to allow only a subset of those fields, any subset as long as the field name is legitimate.

Do I really have to create two separate serializers for it? I can't find a way to define those two different behaviors in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh. Duh. By adding `partial=True` to the serializer declaration, an .update can be partial without errors.